# Reading custom param values from ASX file in WMP control

Tags: vb.net, wmp, asx

Does anybody have an idea how to read the values from custom  fields in a WMP ASX Metafile?

I know its possible as I'd done it in a VB6 app i'd done a while back (which i've lost the source to), but am now trying to do it in a VB.net project.

I've tried searching Microsofts MSDN documentation online, but havent found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical...after weeks of searching, on the day i ask for help, i find it!!

In case anyone else is wondering, you need to use

```
currentMedia.getItemInfo()
```

More info is available on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)